# Why can I access unistd.h in windows?

Tags: c, windows, posix

I'm running Codeblocks on Windows platform. When studying about POSIX superset standard in C I came across some incompatibilities. I do understand that POSIX standard is designed to work on unix like systems whereas on windows I should search for the equivalents.

The problem I encounter is that for example (from wikipedia)

> In the C and C++ programming languages, unistd.h is the name of the header file that provides access to the POSIX operating system API. It is defined by the POSIX.1 standard, the base of the Single Unix Specification, and should therefore be available in any POSIX-compliant operating system and compile

But when I include `unistd.h` in my IDE, I get no errors. Of course, I miss some [of the defines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) but surprisingly for me it works. I was expecting an error when including the library. For example, on ubuntu running the same IDE with the same compiler I got error when including `Windows.h` header which makes sense. Why doesn't it works both ways?

- Also, why do I have on windows access to functions for unix like systems (found in POSIX standard)?
- Is there any conversions my compiler does? It automatically converts POSIX standard to windows compatible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `Windows.h` is specific to Windows, therefore it's not surprising that on a a non Windows platform it doesn't exist. You can include `unistd.h` on your platform because the platform provides it. Posix is not related to a particular platform

Comment: windows does not respect POSIX standard as I can understand, POSIX is unix like system related standard. Why do I have acces to `unistd.h` from windows

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX_for_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: @Jabberwocky so basically (bc i don't have cygwin) mingw via MSVCRT.DLL gives some of POSIX standard api?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu I think that's just the C runtime. Mingw has inherited some stuff from Cygwin I believe, so it might come with various Cygwin libs.

Comment: thank you, I've installed cygwin and now I have acces to more elements from POSIX standard than before. I will compile like this for now. But one question still remains in my mind: should I use unistd or windows.h for low level I/O?

Answer (score 2):

Mingw (the default Codeblocks compiler) provides some of those headers inside the include directory of the installation. It has some manner of POSIX support, but I don't think it is 100% compliant. If you want to be certain to run *nix/POSIX compliant libraries under Windows, you should probably use Cygwin instead.

Comment: should I use POSIX functions or use win32 API ? Meaning: should I run cygwin and make use of the facility of posix, or use windows.h library for low level I/O?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu That depends on your requirements. What is the target system(s), what level of portability is required and so on. If you only mean to support Windows, there's no need for POSIX.